# Embed instagram into Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, embed, instagram, instagram-api

I have an Android app with a WebView where I show content that includes embedded twits and embedded instagram photos.

In both cases I copy the blockquote as indicated in the documentation, and I show it this way:

```
    String html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><style>a {color:#333333;}</style></head><body>"+content.substring(0, blockquoteEnd)+"<script async src=\"//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script></body></html>";
    WebView tText = new WebView(getActivity());
    tText.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    WebSettings webSettings = tText.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    textWrapper.addView(tText);
```

My Tweets where shown only in plain text but I fixed this with this line:

```
tText.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://twitter.com", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

I've tried to do the same with Instagram photos doing this:

```
tText.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://instagram.com", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

but it's not working, all instagram photos only show the description in plain text.

I can not find any documentation (official or not) on how to embed Instagram in Android WebViews. Anyone has any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Did you fix what problem? I put embed instagram html to my `WebView` but instead of actual images I see instagram logo.

Comment: No, sorry, I couldn't find a fix for this.

Comment: I just tried set baseUrl to `https://instagram.com` and blocks started to loading images, but resize wrong (images overlap, or are clipped).

Comment: Anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

After trying a lot of combinations and referencing the other answers here, this worked for me:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://instagram.com", myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: I was trying load a blockquote into webview and with loadDataWithBaseURL() method works for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using this link?
https://instagram.com/developer/embedding/

I'm not sure what your "html" param is when you're trying to embed Instagram, but assuming you have the link for the item you want to embed, you can send a request to http://api.instagram.com/oembed with the item's URL and get the relevant information (see the bottom part in the link, "Embedding for developers"); once you get a response, you should be able to retrieve the "html" part from the JSON object and pass that to loadDataWithBaseURL as the second parameter.

Also, I was trying to embed Instagram and Facebook videos on my Android app and was unable to, as I was calling loadDataWithBaseURL with null as the first param, instead of the Instagram/FB URL. Earlier today I saw your questions and noticed that your first param was different than mine, so I changed it, and then everything was OK. So thanks for that :-)

Comment: Perhaps there's a more specific mobile tutorial now, but when I posted my answer, this was the only way I found to embed Instagram in my mobile app - using a WebView, and so the web tutorial was helpful, or at least for me at was..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here the method loadDataWithBaseURL(), in a first parameter it required baseUrl. I had googled about baseUrl, somewhere I found suggestions like it keep only null,"", or Fake://. But my problem was not solved but after that, I gave baseUrl of my website where from embed Instagram redirect and I resolve my issue. And also Twitter video playing issue resolved.

go through https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html at loadData section here you will get the idea.