# Signing in to social media websites on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to sign in to different social media websites (for starters I'm interested for Facebook, Twitter and Instagram) from a single Page of the app, not for user authentication purposes for the app, but specifically for users to be signed in when they are going to visit these specific websites through a hybrid Webview that the app implements.

Answer (score 0):

The xamarin forms webview called the platform native webview. And for the Facebook, the login support on Android WebViews has been deprecated. You can refer to the this case about [Unable to login to facebook from webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75393653/unable-to-login-to-facebook-from-webview).

So for the facebook, you can't do that. And for the twitter and the instagram login page, you can refer to the case about [WebView does not load Instagram login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65532618/webview-does-not-load-instagram-login-page) and the case about [Embed instagram into Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402199/embed-instagram-into-android-webview).

Generally speaking, this depends on if the media website support login in hte platform webview. You can check the website official document to ensure this.

Comment: Well, I don't have a problem with signing in from within the WebView. I just did it on both Facebook and Instagram without an issue on an Android 10 smartphone! What I'm asking is if it is possible to log in from another Page of the app, not from a WebView, and be kept logged in to the same sites when opening them in the WebView on another Page of the app.

Comment: All the webviews in the same app on the android use the same cookie. So you may get that.

Comment: Yes, no doubt about that. What I would like to do is to offer a different Page for the logins, in order for the users to be already signed in when visiting the WebView.